# meteor.call does not call method from meteor.method

Tags: meteor

i have an issue with callback method.

i have created on methods.js in server folder
and one callback.js file in client/test/mytest folder.

my callback.js contains following code

```
Template.testHello.events({
  "click #testHello": function(e) {
    Meteor.call("testmethod",function(error, id) {
      if (error) {
        Errors.throwError(error.reason);
      }
      return false;
    });

    return false;
  }
});
```

and methods.js file code is

```
Meteor.methods({
testmethod: function(att) {
    alert("hello testmethod..");
  }
});
```

but when i clicked on button "testHello" then it gives me error like "internal server error 500".

can anyone have idea about this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to have client-only method calls because Meteor methods are intended to perform RMI (remote method invokation) on the server.

Move your `methods.js` to either `server/methods.js` or `lib/methods.js` if you want your method to have a simulation counterpart on the client.

EDIT :

As hinted by @user728291, the `alert` method is defined on the `window` object which is a browser related object thus only available on client environment, you can use `console.log` instead to print something on the server.

Comment: ok, i have moved my methods.js to server/ folder but it still gives same error.

Comment: I think you are now getting a different error, that alert() is not a function on server.